# Changing design of font-awesome HTML element

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to color and/or design font-awesome html element
to my needs. However it does not change it's original design. why ?
here is the code:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="color:white"></i>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Where is you´r code? Just use `color: #ff0000;`

Comment: Add a semicolon to it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this tag at the button of your body your `<body>`.

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js</script>
```

> FontAwesome is a Javascript file, not a CSS. It needs to be loaded
>   after the DOM.

```css
.icon-color {
  color: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-3x icon-color"></i> 
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv0scmaL/11/) so you can play with it.

You can also do it as Inline style

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-3x icon-color" style="color: #3b5998"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include: `<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` in your `<head>`

Comment: No ! I had a <script> and i added yours too. the facebook <i> element stays the same. black.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `<i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style="color:white"></i>`
**fa** is written as **fab**
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

move the fontawesome-all.js into your project directory, to avoid path errors.
and add this into your code to load the js files.

```
<head>
  <!--load everything-->
  <script defer src="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
</head>
```

then you can start placing icons in your HTML's `<body>`